# Why i am getting different result just on increasing a column in Select clause, how can I solve this?

Tags: sql-server

When I am executing the following query, I am getting 14 rows returned, and execution time is 5 secs.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    B.From_Date, B.To_Date 
FROM 
    dbo.BillingLog BL WITH(NOLOCK) 
JOIN 
    dbo.Billing B WITH(NOLOCK) ON (BL.BillingLogID = B.BillingLogID)
JOIN 
    dbo.BillingDTE BDTE WITH(NOLOCK) ON (B.BillingID = BDTE.BillingID)
JOIN 
    dbo.Batch Bch WITH(NOLOCK) ON (BL.BillingLogID = Bch.BatchID)
JOIN 
    dbo.BatchHeader BH WITH(NOLOCK) ON (Bch.BatchId = BH.BatchId)
JOIN 
    dbo.BatchLine BL WITH(NOLOCK) ON (BH.BatchHeaderId = BL.BatchHeaderId)
```

But when I am running the same query but with only one additional column, I am getting approx 140000 rows and execution time is around 20 secs

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    B.From_Date, B.To_Date, BDTE.Billing_id
FROM 
    dbo.BillingLog BL WITH(NOLOCK)
JOIN 
    dbo.Billing B WITH(NOLOCK) ON (BL.BillingLogID = B.BillingLogID)
JOIN 
    dbo.BillingDTE BDTE WITH(NOLOCK) ON (B.BillingID = BDTE.BillingID)
JOIN 
    dbo.Batch Bch WITH(NOLOCK) ON (BL.BillingLogID = Bch.BatchID)
JOIN 
    dbo.BatchHeader BH WITH(NOLOCK) ON (Bch.BatchId = BH.BatchId)
JOIN 
    dbo.BatchLine BL WITH(NOLOCK) ON (BH.BatchHeaderId = BL.BatchHeaderId)
```

Kindly suggest why I am getting this difference in result only by adding one column in select clause.

Comment: because distinct is applied on the extra column as well, which results in increase in No. of distict rows. you can check this by removing distinct, both queries should return same no of rows.

Comment: DISTINCT Applies to all columns,so by adding a new column the number of distinct rows grows.

Comment: Set [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is ***NOT RECOMMENDED*** to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per previous commentators, DISTINCT will play a part. Also check that you have appropriate indexes on each of your JOIN tables\columns. As you are only selecting columns from two tables the Optimiser shouldn't have to go to the data pages to look at the data rows for most of your join tables (i.e it only needs to look in the indexes). They should be accessed via an index seek (possibly clustered depending on how you sort your rows on disk). It's therefore important if you haven't already setup indexes to ensure you have them! I'm sure this will speed you query up somewhat!

e.g.

```
Billing on BillingLogID (possibly including From_Date & To_Date)
BillingDTE on BillingID
Batch on BillingLogID  (<== Side note, does batchId equal BillingLogID ?)
BatchHeader on BatchId
BatchLine on BatchHeaderId
```

etc